# How can I pinpoint a specific UTxO using ContractModel

Tags: plutus

I'm trying to create a contract where a `TxOutRef` is supplied to it which tells it a specific UTxO to use in the contract. This seemed fine until I started working with `ContractModel`. I can't find any way to pass on information about UTxOs that I create. `nextState` allows me to update the state, but I can't get any contract related info there. `perform` lets me get info from the contracts, but doesn't let me update the state.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding your question correctly. I'm hearing two things here:

**How do I include a specific UTxO in a transaction required by a script?**

[Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/7f7aca8500105d3a0830b40627f1821c9ac7b58e/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Currency.hs#L156) is an example of off-chain code including an arbitrary UTxO to create "one shot", single issued currency.

In this case it doesn't matter which UTxO it is, as long as the `TxOutRef` (`txOutRef`) referenced in the `OneShotCurrency` (`thisCurrency`) is spent with the minting transaction:

```
    let theCurrency = mkCurrency txOutRef amounts
        ...
        mintTx      = Constraints.mustSpendPubKeyOutput txOutRef
                        <> Constraints.mustMintValue (mintedValue theCurrency)
```

**How do I to choose a specific UTxO "that I created?"**

One way is how the oracle is grabbed from the `ContractHandle` in the [Oracle example](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/8cbc68d146c82cc95d9be44c30e049aba3774003/code/week06/src/Week06/Oracle/Test.hs#L70). The `Oracle` value is stored in the `ContractHandle` monad as a `Last` and can be grabbed inside the runtime context with the `getOracle` function.

The logic for actually finding the UTxO is the the `findOracle` function [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/8cbc68d146c82cc95d9be44c30e049aba3774003/code/week06/src/Week06/Oracle/Core.hs#L176).

An alternative approach is in the [Uniswap example](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/7f7aca8500105d3a0830b40627f1821c9ac7b58e/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Uniswap/OffChain.hs#L173). An NFT is created with `Currency.mintContract` and then immediately used as the NFT (`c`) for the Factory Datum here:

```
tx   = mustPayToTheScript (Factory []) $ unitValue c
```

This approach avoids managing the UTxO directly.